# Attributing values depending of another value w/ VBA ? Excel 2010

Tags: excel, vba, date, time, excel-2010

First of all, sorry if it already exists but I can't find the words in English to describe rapidly my question, hence I don't know how to search for it. Skip to third paragraph if you only need the question.

I'm using Excel to build a complete document about my work hours (arrived at, finished at, if I've been late and of how long was I late, overtime, etc etc).
I'm using VBA to smooth this task.

My workplace cuts everything into quarter of hours, which means that if you're late by one minute, you'll lose 15 minutes. If you work overtime for 14 minutes, it won't be seen as overtime. If I point at 07:45 (I'm using 24H format, not AM/PM) I'm fine. If I do it at 07:46 it'll be counted as 08:00. Same with 16:14, it'll show up as 16:00 (details are shown but on the corrected sheet used for salary, it'll show this way). If I do it at 16:15 I've confirmed my 15 minutes of overtime.

So while I could do some workarounds, what I've got in mind is shitcode, really. I'd like to know a **good** (clean) way to do this : I want for every timestamps I input to be cut in degressive quarter of hours (for instance, I want 17:12 to show up as 17:00 or 08:57 as 08:45).

Thanks for your help, if you didn't understand something or doubt about something I've said, it's probably because of the way I explained it, please ask whatever's needed :)

Update 01: Values are indeed Time processed by Excel, not Strings looking like a timestamp.

Update 02: Solved by @FunThomas with `TimeSerial`-command and some explanations. Thanks, I hope this can be of help for future reference, however I lack the words to write a better title for this problem.

Comment: How are you planning to achieve this? Using formulas? Writing vba code?

Comment: As I said, I'm using VBA (in the title and in the text).

Comment: Then post your code and explain where are you having problems.

Comment: My code isn't the problem, I have a workaround in mind, I'm not using it because it's a dirty code and isn't worth the investment in time to write since I'm sure a "good, clean" way to do what I want to do already exist. I'm asking if someone knows such a "good, clean" code to use.
My problem is already explained otherwise.
Edit: What I mean is, my code doesn't include this yet, so it would be pointless to post it here.

Comment: What I'm understanding is that you don't have a code and you want a code for free.

Comment: I have a way to achieve it but to write down that code would take time as it's uselessly long for what needs to be done. I don't want a code for free, even throwing a link which covers this topic would do, this is most likely something every single people learning VBA would learn to do, however I only have knowkledge of the very basics of VBA and this not my work either. I also don't know the function used for this and lack the words in english to search for this specific function as I don't know how I should formulate my sentence to actually get results out of the search.

Comment: David, I'm only here to ask for "some" help, not for my worksheet to be coded by someone else, I only ask the string of code I don't know about (how could I write something I don't actually KNOW about ?). I'm requesting some help to figure this out, if you don't wish to help it's fine, but don't blame me for not writting a code that'll make me lose an incredible amount of time for virtually nothing while I expect a function to exist which would make this way shorter.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you data is really time (and not a string that looks like time) and is stored in Cell A1, you can use a formula like this:

```
=TIME(HOUR(A1), INT(MINUTE(A1)/15) * 15, 0)
```

The `time`-command gets three paramater (hour, minute, second).
The hour-part is simple.
For the minute, we make an integer division by 15 (resulting in values from 0..3) and multiply it back with 15 (to get 0, 15, 30 or 45).
The second is simply set to 0.

**Update**: 
As VBA-function:

```
Function roundTime(t As Date) as date
    roundTime = TimeSerial(Hour(t), Int(Minute(t) / 15) * 15, 0)
End Function
```

Comment: Data is really time.
I tried to make a new sheet to try it out, filled A1 with 15:32 displayed as 15:32:00
So far, great. I create a commandbutton, write the code as : 
`Cells(10, 1).Value = Time(Hour(A1), Int(Minute(A1) / 15) * 15, 0)`
but it tells me "Execution error "13" ; Type incompability".
Oh, my bad. You wrote a formula, not VBA. I'll be trying again.

Comment: Thank you for providing the function in VBA !
I wrote this `t = Cells(1, 1).Value
` `Cells(1, 2).Value = TimeSerial(Hour(t), Int(Minute(t) / 15) * 15, 0)` to test it and it works flawlessly. You made my day.
Seems my votes aren't visible yet but I definitely upped your answer.
If I could, I'd bake you a cookie right now. That was the only thing I didn't know but needed to keep writting my code.